# How can I make an element visible on a page only when the html content height is bigger than the viewport height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, viewport

I have this page which is basically a to do list, where you can add an infinite number of tasks of every kind, and of course, if you add a lot of tasks the height of the page is going to get bigger, and the scollbar is going to appear. I also have this button fixed at the bottom right of the page, and its only function is to send you back to the top of the page.
What I would like to do is to set the button's display to none only in case the page height is not bigger than the viewport height (so it can't scroll), because it would just be useless in this case, and then set its display to block in case the page has become higher than 100vh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to check if the `window.scrollY` position value is `0`. If not, you can assume that the page content is taller than the viewport and that the page is scrolled, so you can show/hide a "back to top" button accordingly. For example:

### Javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const toTopLink = document.getElementById('toTopLink');

  if (window.scrollY > 0) {
    toTopLink.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    toTopLink.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

### HTML

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>

<a id="toTopLink" class="hidden" href="#">Scroll to Top</a>
```

### CSS

```css
#toTopLink {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  /* ... */
}

#toTopLink.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing this solution in action (note that you will need to resize your window height accordingly to see scroll behavior):

https://jsfiddle.net/dwq4h82x/8/

---

### Smooth scroll and fade in/out of button

For some added goodness, you could do something like this instead of toggling `display: none`:

https://jsfiddle.net/6bjhvte4/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'm haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure this could be done with @media queries:

```css
.topbutton {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 100vh) {
    .topbutton {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this option, but unfortunately it always show the button, I think it's because you are measuring the viewport-height which is going to be always 100vh of itself. We should show the button only when the body is higher than 100vh, and not the screen itself, because is always 100vh of itself.  I'm sure it can be done using media queries, but with different values.

Comment: ... you're absolutely right, full-on derp moment from me there sorry! Might not be doable w/ media queries after all, as you care about the `<body>`'s height, not the viewport's

Comment: Using JS you could check `body.scrollHeight > body.offsetHeight` (or something similar) and use that to show it. Then again if you're using JS the better option might be to check `body.scrollTop > 0` and use that to show/hide (that way it'll only show once the page is scrolled)

Comment: Fairly certain this can't be achieved with CSS alone. Needs a bit of javascript to measure stuff.